# "You'll bury every gerbil's face in his face, yeah!"?

Tags: spoken-english

This is about some [**audio**](https://youtu.be/VuCTmbB1XX0?t=3m24s) clip in an old school coin-up game ([*Wrestlefest*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WWF_WrestleFest)). You end up fighting against the [*Legion of Doom*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Road_Warriors) and you're presented with a cut scene where *Road Warrior "Animal"* and *Road Warrior "Hawk"* are interviewed:

> Gene Okerlund: *It's time to fight with a powerful challenger...*
>   RW-A: *Haha, we snack on danger, right on, yeah!*
>  RW-H: [You'll
>   bury every gerbil's face in his face, yeah!]

Obviously, [Michael Hegstrand](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Road_Warrior_Hawk) (RW-H) was not saying that but this is what I hear...

---

What is he saying exactly?

Comment: I hear something like: _"To bury every gerbil-faced geek we face."_

Comment: BTW - _"We snack on danger, **dine on death**"_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hear this:

> Gene Okerlund: It's time to fight with a powerful challenger...
>
> RW-A: Haha, we snack on danger, **dine on death!**
>
> RW-H: To bury every gerbil-faced geek we face.!

I could be convinced that *geek* is actually *team,* but the *gerbil* is very clear.

FWIW, I don't remember *"gerbil-faced"* being a common insult in the '80's.

Comment: Thank you! I've revisited the audio many times. Imho, there is not enough space for "death" to fit; I have a very high confidence level that the final word is "yeah" and your interpretation makes it more (too) clever imho. I remembered the line from memory after someone said "right on", but I'm no native speaker, and more importantly I fully agree with how you read the second part with the _gerbil_; undoubtedly "gerbil-faced geek"! I remember hearing this expression before, couldn't say when/where exactly. Thanks again!

Comment: It's definitely _"Snack on danger, dine on death."_  That was a catchphrase of the road warriors back in the day - their standard sign-off at the end of a "press conference."  There's more than a few Youtube examples of it, for instance: https://youtu.be/hvopuRIAmPE?t=2m37s ....And this native speaker hears it very clearly in the video game clip.

Comment: Another one: https://youtu.be/gHXFDAdMYmg?t=1m34s